# JPQL query not using "NOT IN" command

Tags: java, jpa, jpa-2.0, jpql

I'm trying to exclude a bunch of results from a database SELECT using the "NOT IN" keywords, but the exclusion list is still being returned.  Using JPQL (JPA2.0) my query looks like:

```
Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT foo.id FROM FooEntity fooEntity WHERE foo.id NOT IN ('" + exclusionList.toString() + "') ORDER BY foo.id").setFirstResult(startPosition).setMaxResults(numberOfAppsToReturn);
```

exclusionList is a StringBuffer.  There is no error reported that I can see, but the id's in the exclusion list are still returned.  Is there an alternative JPQL way of doing this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the mistake is in `foo`. What is foo you have to defined it any where.

Write `FooEntity foo` instead of `FooEntity fooEntity`

Have a look on the following URL.

[JPQL, How to NOT select something](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1578644/jpa-ql-how-to-not-select-something)

Comment: Hi Deepak, just discovered the problem was within my stringBuilder, I was surrounding the entire list with a single quote, rather than surrounding each item in the list with a single quote.  Eg, ('item1,item2,item3...') instead of ('item1','item2','item3'...)  I'll vote for your answer anyway to say thanks for responding.