# How to express not in M:N relation with JPA 2.0 Criteria?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa-2.0, criteria-api

How to express a query with JPA 2.0 Criteria that should fetch all entities A that are not in relation (m:n) with an Entity B.

Domain Model:

```
@Entity class A{
  @Id int id;
  @ManyToMany List<B> disableForB;
}

@Entity class B{
  @Id int id;
}
```

The problem related to this domain model is: How to find all `A` that are not in relation `disableForB` for an specific `B`?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1578644/jpa-ql-how-to-not-select-something

Comment: @David Holbrook: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1578644/jpa-ql-how-to-not-select-something discuss this problem for JPQL but not for Criteria API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not have environment to test query available at the moment, so following can contain some mistake. This is anyway doable with [isNotMember](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html#isNotMember%28E,%20javax.persistence.criteria.Expression%29).

```
B b ...
CriteriaQuery<Aa> cq = cb.createQuery(A.class);
ParameterExpression<B> param = cb.parameter(B.class);
Root<A> a = cq.from(A.class);
Expression<Collection<B>> disabledB = a.get("disableForB");
Predicate pred = cb.isNotMember(param, disabledB);
cq.select(a);
cq.where(pred);
em.createQuery(cq).setParameter(param, b).getResultList();
```